# Oracle 11g database server parameter tuning

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle11g, database-tuning

I have a 4 Core 12GB RAM dedicated windows machine.I have Oracle 11g installed on it.

Could any body please help on the DB server parameters that can be tuned from a performance perspective.

Any reference to a credible url also is fine & will be of great help. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Oracle provides a lot of online documentation including a lot of guides. The [2 Day DBA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm#BEGIN) Guide for 11.2 has a section on Monitoring and Tuning the Database that can get you started. Other sections in the guide can be helpful as well.